# What's the correct definition of Decentralized Applications?

Tags: dapps, decentralization

What's the correct definition of Decentralized Applications? Some, like https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/your-first-dapp
points the two layer architecture (web/front layer and the ledger), but others (http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781491924549_sampler.pdf) focus on 4 main features (open source, internal cryptocurrency, consensus and no central point of failure).
May I say a true Dapp is a two layer app (frontend + ledger) following all the four principles?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-is-a-dapp