# Dapps & IPFS vs smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, ipfs

Wouldn't a dapp deployed on IPFS + "link" (the hash of the dapp) to the dapp on the blockchain act exactly like a smart contract?

I make this statement, because the app would be immutable due to IPFS and the "link" to the app would be also immutable too, due to how blockchains work. This is exactly like with a smart contract. The smart contract is also immutable. And this would remove the necessity to store the smart contract code on the blockchain.

Is this a fallacy?

Comment: A smart contract functions as the backend to your DAPP. How does IPFS execute “server side” code?

Comment: Please see the following question that explains DApp architecture: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/what-elements-of-a-dapps-backend-are-usually-stored-in-a-decentralised-location/11930#11930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "dapp" was just a set of static webpages, yes, it would be immutable, but it would make little sense, and I wouldn't even call it a dapp.

The concept of a dapp is a dynamic web app that fetches data from a decentralized data source, AKA a smart contract.

If you remove the smart contract from the equation, you are left with an immutable front-end which either holds static data or it fetches the data from a non-decentralized source like a database.

That database from where this app fetches data could be taken down, censored, modified, etc, etc.