# Is an Ethereum paper wallet generator considered a dapp?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, dapps, dapp-design

I made an Ethereum paper wallet generator. Is this considered a dapp as it can be downloaded and run without any central server to generate ethereum addresses? Or does a dapp have to be tied to a specific token of some sort? What are some good examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider your app being a standalone utility.

Take a look at "[What is a DApp?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-is-a-dapp)" for a pretty detailed description on what a DAPP is.