# What programming languages was Uniswap's open-source code written in?

Tags: assembly, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, defi

Uniswap is a decentralized exchange that is actually a decentralized app where people can trade ERC-20 tokens without a middleman.

Uniswap's code is open-source:

- https://github.com/Uniswap

Was the Uniswap code written purely in **solidity**, given the high number of `.sol` filename extensions? What other programming languages were involved?

Separate from the underlying architecture, how about the [Uniswap interface](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-interface), which I assume is the GUI that we interact with in our web browser when actually trading/swapping tokens. What language was it written in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniswap protocol is developed in **Solidity**, and you can find two main building blocks:

- *uniswap-v2-core*: Core smart contracts, essentially with the Factory, Pair and ERC20, together with a number of interfaces and libraries.
- *uniswap-v2-periphery*: additional smart contracts to interact with the Core ones. They simplify the process of doing swaps or adding/removing liquidity.

Unless you have to do very specific or complex actions with this protocol, it is easier to use the periphery contracts by just calling the [necessary functions](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/).

On the other hand, there is already a user interface in which you can interact directly with the smart contracts without the need of coding anything. This [interface](https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap) is built with **React** using **TypeScript** and the **@web3-react** library to interact with Ethereum's smart contracts.

Comment: so Solidity is not only for writing smart contracts, but also for writing DApps?

Comment: A Dapp has several components, being the smart contracts the core one. You can find more details on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-is-a-dapp

Comment: most webmasters can only code in HTML, CSS, Javascript. Is there now a new breed of "DApp webmasters" that specialize in React, TypeScript and web3-react that sets them apart from the old school web designers? What is a good meeting hub to solicit such developers for a new project?

Comment: Knowing JavaScript, webmasters essentially need to learn either web3.js or ethers.js to interact with Ethereum. As for the framework, it can be React, Flutter, Angular, Vue... but I would say React seems to be quite a standard. To find developers: https://cryptojobslist.com/ , https://cryptocurrencyjobs.co/ , https://crypto.jobs/ , etc.