# What happens if a dapp website goes down?

Tags: dapps

Is it possible for a dapp like AAVE to remain up and running on the blockchain, but the website to fail?  If that happened, how would people access their balances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [dapp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-is-a-dapp) website is a UI that makes it easier to use smart contracts.

If the website goes down, you still be able to send transactions to the smart contracts.  You could do it by using a library like ethers.js, or by [interacting with smart contracts on Etherscan](https://medium.com/etherscan-blog/interacting-with-smart-contracts-on-etherscan-b3e1d2395ac).

---

Some smart contracts have multiple UIs that you might not be aware of.  For example, Uniswap is a couple of smart contracts that other sites or aggregators make use of.  If the Uniswap website goes down, you could use the other sites and  specify that you only want to route your trades to Uniswap.