# Deploying Meteor Dapps

Tags: dapps, meteor

What are currently the best architectural and deployment options for building and deploying a Dapp built with Meteor/Web3?

For building the Dapp, a few Meteor packages are currently available :

1. "Dapp Using Meteor" contains key Meteor packages
2. Meteor Build Client : https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-build-client

In practice, Meteor apps are hosted on a server.  How can a Meteor Dapp be deployed so that all users who access it on the web can interact with the blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

The result of Meteor Build Client should be static web assets (HTML, CSS, JS) that can be hosted on any web server or [content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). Aligning with the goals of a [fully decentralized web](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/08/18/building-decentralized-web/), these files would eventually live on the [Swarm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/388/43) component of the Ethereum network.

Strictly speaking, Meteor Build Client has nothing to do with Etheruem, however if using [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) to interact with the Ethereum network, web3.js will need a node to connect to, either locally (i.e. in Mist) or via a proxy, such as with [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) browser.

Comment: For now, does the built app become an Ethereum node or does it have to connect to a remote node?

Comment: Answer updated with information about connecting to an Ethereum node