# How to store image data in smart contract in hexadecimal format?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to store image data as hex in a smart contract. How can i do so. I am not able to find a way to convert image to hex in javascript. How can i do that as well?

Comment: Is this for a proof-of-concept on a private network, or a real-life, main net contract? If it's the latter, it's going to be (very) expensive. Your best bet would be to store it offchain... See: [Image attached to Ethereum contract (off-chain)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17249/image-attached-to-ethereum-contract-off-chain)

Comment: I will actually store the hash of the data, not the entire data, so i just want to convert image to data array.

Comment: Aha, okay, in that case the previous question I've linked to should help. It looks like one of the answers also contains some pointers to examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just get byte data of the image offline with a small script and then pass that in as bytes32, hash with keccak, and store in smart contract?